# Set display of jQuery show hide toggle in css

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

The reason I want to set display in CSS is because all pages need specific content expanded or collapsed varying from page to page. As it is now, it seems like I'll need to load a different JS file for each page's display preferences. I'd just like to keep it all centralized in one file...

CSS:

```
div.expandable1 {display:block;}
div.expandable2 {display:none;}  [etc]
```

HTML:

```
<p id="tab1" class="button plus1">NEWS -</p>
<div class="expandable1 panel1" id="one">
[content]
</div>
```

JS:

```
        $(".button").show();
        $('.plus1').toggle(function(){
            $("#one").slideDown(
            function(){
                $(".plus1").text("NEWS -")
            }
            );
        },function(){
            $("#one").slideUp(
                function(){
                    $(".plus1").text("NEWS +")
                }
            );
        });       [etc]
```

### My Question:

How can I use css to control the following:

eg:

```
page A- expandable1 is expanded, expandable2 collapsed 
page B- expandable1 is collapsed, expandable2 expanded
```

etc. There are about 6-8 various page configurations of which of 4-5 sections [expandables 1-6] will need to be displayed in various combinations.

As it is now, I can just use {display:block/none,etc.} as above but my JS buttons get a bit wiggy.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The toggle() function used that way is deprecated, and removed in jQuery 1.9, but what is really the question ?

Comment: yea sorry, wasn't clear. Hope that's better?

Comment: I think I get it. So you'd like one javascript file that expands sections but the logic is only for certain pages. I'l write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Idea 1:

It sounds like you're trying to write logic for each page. Here's a couple ways:

My suggestion would be to use body classes and put it all in CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="pageA">
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* PageA Styles */
.pageA div.expandable1 {display:block;}
.pageA div.expandable2 {display:none;}

/* PageB Styles */
.pageB div.expandable1 {display:none;}
.pageB div.expandable2 {display:block;}
```

## Idea 2

**Javascript Only**
If you need to do this all with javascript, you'll have to detect the page name using the window.location. Not a great way, but definitely doable.

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/pageA/') {
$('div.expandable1').show();
$('div.expandable2').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer StingeyB. Been staring at my screen for too many hrs now... I'll try it out first thing in am. Thx again `:]`